# iOS App Crashes in Release mode on making api request using ServiceStack client in .Net MAUI

Tags: ios, servicestack, maui

I have integrated ServiceStack nuget package in .net maui app and making api request from it. It works fine in debug mode on ios platform, but in Release mode my app crashes. I'm not able to figure out what error it produces and why my app got crashed.

I have tried both ServiceStack Client and ServiceStack Http client packages but both does not work for me.

Comment: Do you have any exception handling or logging in your app?  Based on the limited information provided it’s difficult to give any more specific advice

Comment: I have implemented Sentry logging to it. As I make the api request I got SIGABRT error in my logs.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a result of iOS's NO JIT restrictions which inhibits many .NET libraries that use reflection. For the best chance of working you should [prevent linking Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?tabs=vs#preserve-assemblies) containing Types used in serialization, e.g. your ServiceModel .dll which contain your DTOs.